# O que é e como usar o atributo currentColor no CSS?

Tags: css, css3

O que é o atributo currentColor no CSS?

Para que serve esse atributo e qual a melhor forma de usa-lo? Gostaria de alguns exemplos para poder entender melhor.

Se o elemento não tiver um color ou se o color estiver no pai, como eu posso usar o currentColor no filho... Em suma como funciona e como posso aplicar esse atributo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ele não é um atributo, **o `currentColor` é uma palavra chave** que é usada nos atributos CSS, desde o CSS1 e CSS2 é possível usar em bordas (em `border-color`), o que ele faz é que a propriedade setada receba a mesma cor de fonte definida no elemento ou em um elemento pai.

Um exemplo:

```css
.foo { color: blue; }

.bar { color: red; }

.baz { color: orange; }

.box {
   border: 5px dotted currentColor;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
   <div class="box">olá mundo!</div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
   <div class="box">olá mundo!</div>
</div>

<div class="baz">
   <div class="box">olá mundo!</div>
</div>
```

Veja que as bordas assumem a mesma cor usada nas fontes.

Note que me `border` você pode omitir a cor, que o CSS irá assumir que esta usando `currentColor`, exemplo:

```css
.foo { color: blue; }

.bar { color: red; }

.baz { color: orange; }

.box {
   border: 5px dotted;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
   <div class="box">olá mundo!</div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
   <div class="box">olá mundo!</div>
</div>

<div class="baz">
   <div class="box">olá mundo!</div>
</div>
```

Fonte: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-color-3-20180619/#currentcolor

---

Claro que hoje outras propriedades suportam o `currentColor`, por exemplo, você pode usar para aplicar a mesma cor de fonte e um `box-shadow` ou `text-shadow`, exemplos:

`box-shadow`

```css
.foo { color: blue; }

.bar { color: red; }

.baz { color: orange; }

.box {
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px currentColor;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"> <div class="box">olá mundo!</div> </div>
<div class="bar"> <div class="box">olá mundo!</div> </div>
<div class="baz"> <div class="box">olá mundo!</div> </div>
```

`text-shadow`

```css
.foo { color: blue; }

.bar { color: red; }

.baz { color: orange; }

.foo span, .bar span, .baz span {
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 2px currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"> olá <span>mundo!</span> </div>
<div class="bar"> olá <span>mundo!</span> </div>
<div class="baz"> olá <span>mundo!</span> </div>
```

---

Um exemplo interessante que adotei em meu "framework" é para criar/simular setinhas (arrows) para menus dropdowns para navbars ou combobox simulados como `border:`, ficou assim (só vou trazer a parte que é relevante para aprendizado mesmo):

```css
[class^="v-arrow-"], [class*=" v-arrow-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: .3em solid transparent;
}

.v-arrow-left {
  border-right: .3em solid currentColor; /*pode omitir o currentColor que terá o mesmo efeito*/
  border-left: 0;
}

.v-arrow-right {
  border-left: .3em solid currentColor; /*pode omitir o currentColor que terá o mesmo efeito*/
  border-right: 0;
}

.v-arrow-up, .v-arrow-down {
  vertical-align: .15em;
  border-top: .3em solid currentColor; /*pode omitir o currentColor que terá o mesmo efeito*/
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.v-arrow-up {
  border-bottom: .3em solid currentColor; /*pode omitir o currentColor que terá o mesmo efeito*/
  border-top: 0;
}

/*-- cores nos elementos "pais" --*/

.foo1 { color: red; }
.foo2 { color: pink; }
.foo3 { color: orange; }
```

```html
Seta/arrow para cima: <i class="v-arrow-up"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para baixo: <i class="v-arrow-down"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para esquerda: <i class="v-arrow-left"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para direita: <i class="v-arrow-right"></i>

<div class="foo1">
Seta/arrow para cima: <i class="v-arrow-up"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para baixo: <i class="v-arrow-down"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para esquerda: <i class="v-arrow-left"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para direita: <i class="v-arrow-right"></i>
</div>

<div class="foo2">
Seta/arrow para cima: <i class="v-arrow-up"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para baixo: <i class="v-arrow-down"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para esquerda: <i class="v-arrow-left"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para direita: <i class="v-arrow-right"></i>
</div>

<div class="foo3">
Seta/arrow para cima: <i class="v-arrow-up"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para baixo: <i class="v-arrow-down"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para esquerda: <i class="v-arrow-left"></i><br>
Seta/arrow para direita: <i class="v-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta meu querido!