# Alterar côr do cenário com botão

Tags: javascript, html, parallax

Estou a criar um cenário com Parallax e queria simular alteração de cores nas montanhas, para isso, a côr será escolhida pelo utilizador.
Tenho 3 botões para o efeito.

[image: HTML]

O meu problema é que não sei como vou fazer para as montanhas mudarem de côr visto que inicializam com uma côr fixa.

O HTML está praticamente feito:

```
<div id="game">
<button class="user" data-name="red">Red</button>
<button class="user" data-name="green">Green</button>
<button class="user" data-name="blue">Blue</button>
<button id="test">Change Color</button>
```

A minha dúvida é como vou fazer as montanhas começarem a ficar com a côr selecionada, nem sei se faz sentido ter o botão "Change Color".

O código JavaScript do setup é o seguinte:

```
id="rendered-js">
      (function () {
  var Montanha, MontanhaRange, dt, MontanhaRanges, janela;

  janela = Sketch.create();

  janela.mouse.x = janela.width / 10;

  janela.mouse.y = janela.height;

  MontanhaRanges = [];

  dt = 1;
  p = 90;

  Montanha = function (config) {
    return this.reset(config);
  };

$(document).ready(function() {
    var user = "none";
    $(".user").click(function() {
        user = $(this).attr("data-name");
    });
        $("#test").click(function() {
        window.location.reload();
        p = 240
    });
});

// Montanhas

  Montanha.prototype.reset = function (config) {
    this.layer = config.layer;
    this.x = config.x;
    this.y = config.y;
    this.width = config.width;
    this.height = config.height;
    return this.color = config.color;
  };

  // Montanha tamanho

  MontanhaRange = function (config) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.Montanhas = [];
    this.layer = config.layer;
    this.width = {
      min: config.width.min,
      max: config.width.max };

    this.height = {
      min: config.height.min,
      max: config.height.max };

    this.speed = config.speed;
    this.color = config.color;
    this.populate();
    return this;
  };

  MontanhaRange.prototype.populate = function () {
    var newHeight, newWidth, results, totalWidth;
    totalWidth = 0;
    results = [];
    while (totalWidth <= janela.width + this.width.max * 4) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
      newWidth = round(random(this.width.min, this.width.max));
      newHeight = round(random(this.height.min, this.height.max));
      this.Montanhas.push(new Montanha({
        layer: this.layer,
        x: this.Montanhas.length === 0 ? 0 : this.Montanhas[this.Montanhas.length - 1].x + this.Montanhas[this.Montanhas.length - 1].width,
        y: janela.height - newHeight,
        width: newWidth,
        height: newHeight,
        color: this.color }));

      results.push(totalWidth += newWidth);
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(0);
    return results;
  };

  MontanhaRange.prototype.update = function () {
    var firstMontanha, lastMontanha, newHeight, newWidth;
    this.x -= janela.mouse.x * this.speed * dt;
    firstMontanha = this.Montanhas[0];
    if (firstMontanha.width + firstMontanha.x + this.x < -this.width.max) {
      newWidth = round(random(this.width.min, this.width.max));
      newHeight = round(random(this.height.min, this.height.max));
      lastMontanha = this.Montanhas[this.Montanhas.length - 1];
      firstMontanha.reset({
        layer: this.layer,
        x: lastMontanha.x + lastMontanha.width,
        y: janela.height - newHeight,
        width: newWidth,
        height: newHeight,
        color: this.color });

      return this.Montanhas.push(this.Montanhas.shift());
    }
  };

  MontanhaRange.prototype.render = function () {
    var c, d, i, j, pointCount, ref;
    janela.save();
    janela.translate(this.x, (janela.height - janela.mouse.y) / 20 * this.layer);
    janela.beginPath();
    pointCount = this.Montanhas.length;
    janela.moveTo(this.Montanhas[0].x, this.Montanhas[0].y);
    for (i = j = 0, ref = pointCount - 2; j <= ref; i = j += 1) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) break;
      c = (this.Montanhas[i].x + this.Montanhas[i + 1].x) / 2;
      d = (this.Montanhas[i].y + this.Montanhas[i + 1].y) / 2;
      janela.quadraticCurveTo(this.Montanhas[i].x, this.Montanhas[i].y, c, d);
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
    janela.lineTo(janela.width - this.x, janela.height);
    janela.lineTo(0 - this.x, janela.height);
    janela.closePath();
    janela.fillStyle = this.color;
    janela.fill();
    return janela.restore();
  };

  // SETUP

  janela.setup = function () {
    var i, results;
    i = 5;
    results = [];
    while (i--) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)) break;
      results.push(MontanhaRanges.push(new MontanhaRange({
        layer: i + 1,
        width: {
          min: (i + 1) * 50,
          max: (i + 1) * 70 },

        height: {
          min: 200 - i * 40,
          max: 300 - i * 40 },

        speed: (i + 1) * .003,
        color: 'hsl(' + p + ', ' + ((i + 1) * 1 + 10) + '%, ' + (75 - i * 13) + '% )' })));
      console.log("Hello world!");

    }window.CP.exitedLoop(2);
    return results;
  };

  // CLEAR

  janela.clear = function () {
    return janela.clearRect(0, 0, janela.width, janela.height);
  };

  // UPDATE

  janela.update = function () {
    var i, results;
    dt = janela.dt < .1 ? .1 : janela.dt / 16;
    dt = dt > 5 ? 5 : dt;
    i = MontanhaRanges.length;
    results = [];
    while (i--) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(3)) break;
      results.push(MontanhaRanges[i].update(i));
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(3);
    return results;
  };

  // DRAW

  janela.draw = function () {
    var i, results;
    i = MontanhaRanges.length;
    results = [];
    while (i--) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(4)) break;
      results.push(MontanhaRanges[i].render(i));
    }window.CP.exitedLoop(4);
    return results;
  };

  // Mousemove Fix

  $(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    janela.mouse.x = e.pageX;
    return janela.mouse.y = e.pageY;
  });

}).call(this);
```

e onde eu defino a côr é na variavel p:

```
color: 'hsl(' + p + ', ' + ((i + 1) * 1 + 10) + '%, ' + (75 - i * 13) + '% )' })));
```

que eu inicializo com 120 porque é o verde:

[image: Cores]

Como posso eu escolher e alterar a seguinte côr, estou a utilizar este código mas não funciona porque faz reload á página e carrega novamente o verde 120:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var user = "none";
    $(".user").click(function() {
        user = $(this).attr("data-name");
    });
        $("#test").click(function() {
        window.location.reload();
        p = 240
    });
});
```

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9750925d9751abeb292977194665014e20190723191111/94cc2ddd87a539708982e527128a207c20190723191111/c790f0

Comment: Acho que vc está complicando uma coisa que daria para fazer apenas com CSS.... Coloque na sua pergunta um exemplo completo, ou pelo menos um link onde de para testar o modelo. Da forma como está fica complicado te responder, até pq não da pra saber se a imagem é um canvas, svg, ou png por exemplo....

Comment: Obrigado pelo reparo, já coloquei o código completo JS,

Answer (score 15):

Segue ai um exemplo basicão só com CSS, o principio é p mesmo, pois usa o `filter: hue-matrix` para controlar o histograma de cor da imagem. E como o `filter()` aceita `transition` vc consegue uma transição suave entre as cores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é ter um grupo de `radio-buttons` escondidos com suas respectivas `labels` que são os btns visíveis da tela. Quando vc clica nessa `label` vc ativa o `radio-btn` correspondente e usando o seletor adjacente `~` vc muda a cora da imagem que está abaixo, mas na mesma hierarquia...

Pra entender melhor segue o código, ele pode ainda ser mais otimizado, mas deixei bem simplão mesmo para vc entender melhor o que foi feito.

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 260px;
    background-image: url(https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180625/khb/kisspng-mountain-cartoon-clip-art-snow-mountain-5b31b86c4dd650.2273242715299851323188.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 20px auto;
    filter: none;
    transition: filter 500ms linear;
}
label {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
[for="green"] {
    background-color: green;
}
[for="blue"] {
    background-color: blue;
}
[for="red"] {
    background-color: red;
}
#green:checked ~ [for="green"] {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#blue:checked ~ [for="blue"] {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#red:checked ~ [for="red"] {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#green:checked ~ .box {
    filter: hue-rotate(70deg);
}
#blue:checked ~ .box {
    filter: hue-rotate(150deg);
}
#red:checked ~ .box {
    filter: hue-rotate(230deg);
}
#nada:checked ~ .box {
    filter: none;
}

[name="cores"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="cores" id="green">
    <input type="radio" name="cores" id="blue">
    <input type="radio" name="cores" id="red">
    <input type="radio" name="cores" id="nada">
    <label for="green">green</label>
    <label for="blue">blue</label>
    <label for="red">red</label>
    <label for="nada">nada</label>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Dica, colocando a imagem com uma cor só.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira deixar a imagem como acima vc precisa seguir alguns passo, tem outras formas de fazer isso usando `[blend-mode][3]` etc, mas como já estamos usando `filter` vou manter assim.

Primeiro tenha em mente que podemos ter mais de um filtro dentro do `filter`. Então eu vou colocar um filtro para deixar a imagem em *preto & branco* usando  `grayscale(100%)`, depois coloco o filter `sepia(100%)` [para dar um tom amarelado homogêneo na imagem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/sepia), eu preciso dessa cor para depois poder usar o `hue-rotate(XXXdeg)` e setar a cor predominante da imagem.

Segue o código simples, apenas aplicando essa técnica na imagem para ficar mais didático...

```css
body {display:flex}
.filtro-green {
    filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100% ) hue-rotate(70deg);
}
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 260px;
    background-image: url(https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180625/khb/kisspng-mountain-cartoon-clip-art-snow-mountain-5b31b86c4dd650.2273242715299851323188.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 20px auto;
    transition: filter 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
com filtros
<div class="box filtro-green"></div>
sem filtros
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Olá,antes de mais muito obrigado pela sua resposta mas o que pretendo não é alterar a cor de fundo mas alterar uma variavel que define a cor da paisagem. Está aqui o que tenho pra já, não consigo colocar aqui o codigo todo mas basta correr o html para se perceber o que quero, https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xq45vq2ox3tms7/Resolucao.rar?dl=0

Comment: @SaPires eu não consegui baixar o dropBox, de qq forma deixei ai uma nova resposta, agora com a função feita com JS, e trocando os valores de acordo com o data-atributo usado no botão. Da uma olhada ai na outra resposta, acho que está mais próximo do que vc precisava.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Primeiramente estou adicionando essa segunda resposta, pois a resposta anterior já ficou bem longa, e nela tratei apenas uma solução com CSS, porém o Autor da Pergunta parece necessitar mesmo de uma resposta em Javacript</sup>

*Para não misturar os assuntos vou fazer essa outra resposta focando apenas no JS, e deixando a outra resposta só com CSS para consulta, pois acho que é de interesse da comunidade.*

**Vamos aos pontos.**

O ideia é usar um *data atributo*, que chamei de `datar-cor` e está presente em cada `button` para trocar o valor de uma variável CSS que vai estar no `:root`. Então quando vc clica no `btn`, ativa uma função que pega o `data-cor` do atributo e bota como valor de `hue-rotate()` de uma variável que está no CSS.

O primeiro passo é criar uma variável no `:root` do CSS para colocarmos o `hue-rotate(XXXdeg)`, eu chamei essa variável de `--cor`.  E vamos trocar o valor dela identificando o `data-cor` do `button` clicado e substituindo o valor dessa `--cor` no css.

No `forEach` do click no `btn` eu tb adicionei na função para fazer um `addClass` .ativo no botão clicado, isso é apenas para dar um feedback para o usuário, mas se vc não quiser é só retirar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As demais informações sobre a transição de cor estão na respostas anterior se te interessar...

Para entender melhor deixei os comentários no código.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const root = document.documentElement;

function mudaCor(bt) {
  //pega o valor do data-cor do botão clicado e coloca como valor da variável --cor no :root;
  btn.forEach((datac) => {
    datac = this.getAttribute('data-cor');
    root.style.setProperty('--cor', datac );
  });

  //coloca classe ativo no btn clicado e remove dos irmãos
  btn.forEach( (limpa) => {
    limpa.classList.remove('ativo');
  })
  bt.currentTarget.classList.add('ativo');
}

// função que ativa quando o btn é clicado
btn.forEach((trocar) => {
  trocar.addEventListener('click', mudaCor);
});
```

```css
:root {
  /* variável de cor que recebe o valor do data-cor do btn clicado */
  --cor: hue-rotate(0deg);
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  background-image: url(https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180625/khb/kisspng-mountain-cartoon-clip-art-snow-mountain-5b31b86c4dd650.2273242715299851323188.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px auto;
  filter: var(--cor);
  transition: filter 500ms linear;
}
button.ativo {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <!-- btns com o data-cor = o valor que vou substituir como valor do --cor no css -->
  <button data-cor="hue-rotate(70deg)">green</button>
  <button data-cor="hue-rotate(170deg)">blue</button>
  <button data-cor="hue-rotate(270deg)">red</button>
  <button class="ativo" data-cor="hue-rotate(0deg)">none</button>

  <div class="box" data-type="uma div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo perdido, tentei adaptar o seu código no meu mas não ficou, talvez por eu nao usar uma imagem fixa mas sim uma montanha gerada seja esse o problema, coloquei o projeto em: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9750925d9751abeb292977194665014e20190723191111/94cc2ddd87a539708982e527128a207c20190723191111/c790f0

Comment: O meu problema é que estou a utilizar Parallax

Comment: @SaPires o problema não é o parallax ao meu vero, o problema é como vc constrói esse parallas com JS, e em que momento vc vai setar as propriedades no elemento que deseja. Parece que é um canvas que vc vai montar. Tente criar um ambiente de deste e vai montado tudo em partes, comece com um elemento único e sem o parallax e tente mudar a cor clicando no btn, e depois vc vai "completando" o script até chegar no ponto que quer

Comment: Mas foi exatamente o que eu fiz, e consigo chegar ao ponto do seu projeto, mas coloco a parte de geração de montanhas e apenas aparecem as montanhas na cor defenida pela variável. Consegui ver o código. Desculpa e obrigado

Comment: @SaPires conseguiu resolver? As vezes vc precisa colocar a função de trocar a cor dentro de um SetTimeout, pois assim o script vai desenhar as montanhas, e só depois que elas "existirem" vc executa a função de trocar a cor alguma coisa assim...

Comment: As montanhas estão a ser formadas ao decorrer da páginas, não é apenas uma vez, são Random constantemente formadas, eu penso que por isso é o problema

Comment: Eu não manjo muito de JS, mas o que vc pode fazer é "salvar" a cor que aplicou na primeira montanha e nas próxima que surgirem vc aplica essa cor. Sei que falando é fácil, mas com essa parte não consigo te ajudar, meu conhecimento é limitado nessa área ainda :/

Comment: não, estou a tentar de tudo mas vou ter de pesquisar outra forma de fazer, está mesmo dificil.

Comment: Tente colocar o projeto rodando em um CodePen ou Jsfiddle, assim fica mais fácil pra gente ver a situação real, ou mesmo em uma GitPage. Pode ser que pegando de alguma forma pelo evento do scroll vc criar a próxima mantanha com a cor da anterior. Até pq com o CurrentColor do CSS vc consegue pegar um cor "base" e passar como background, tipo `background-color: currentColor` Leia mais aqui que pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322824/o-que-%c3%a9-e-como-usar-o-atributo-currentcolor-no-css

Comment: eu nao consigo colocar a rodar online porque tenho varios .css
mas basta correr o html daqui. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9750925d9751abeb292977194665014e20190723191111/94cc2ddd87a539708982e527128a207c20190723191111/c790f0