# Esconder/Mostar um drop-down list de acordo com o Radio selecionado em HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, netbeans

Eu tenho um código que me mostra um radio

E eu tenho um código de um drop-down list que está oculto(`hidden`) e que deve ser exibido somente se o radio estiver `checked`

Eu estou tentando criar uma Função em Javascript para quando o radio estiver checked, o drop-down list apareça, mas não estou conseguindo.
Meu script

Aqui está o código:

```js
var radio01 = document.getElementsByName("radio01");
var ListaOpcoes = document.getElementsByName("ListaOpcoes");
 
function FuncRadio01() {               
   if(radio01[0].checked) {
      // Aqui deve ir código pra exibir o drop-down list,  mas não sei o que colocar.
     // Já tentei "ListaOpcoes.removeAttribute("hidden");" e não funcionou.
    // Já tentei "ListaOpcoes.show();" e não funcionou.
   }
}
```

```html
Clique no botão:<input type="radio" name="radio01" id="radio01" value="radio01" onclick="FuncRadio01()"/>

<select id="ListaOpcoes" name="ListaOpcoes" hidden>
            <option>Selecione</option>
            <option value="opcao01">Opção 01</option>
            <option value="opcao02">Opção 02</option>
            <option value="opcao03">Opção 03</option>
            <option value="opcao04">Opção 04</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Cara primeiro, e MUITO importante, se vc realmente vai usar Radio Buttons? Se sim vc não vai poder usar o `name` como atributo, pois em um "grupo de radios" onde vc marca um e desmarca o outro todos terão o mesmo `name`! Depois eu sugiro vc usar um seletor pelo data-set, aqui tem um exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398049/alterar-c%c3%b4r-do-cen%c3%a1rio-com-bot%c3%a3o/399030#399030

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo, tente isso aqui:

```
<script>
var radio01 = document.getElementsByName("radio01");
var ListaOpcoes = document.getElementsByName("ListaOpcoes");
 
function FuncRadio01() {               
   if(radio01[0].checked) {
      ListaOpcoes.style.display = 'none';
   } else {
      ListaOpcoes.style.display = '';
   }
}
</script>
```